# Function to change import and destination file

Tags: r, function

I need to run the same code over 5 datasets which are too large to bind together. The code exports a table to a destination file which also needs to change depending on the file imported.

Imagine I have the following code :

```
load("file 1", .GlobalEnv)
tab<-table(df$A, df$B)
write.table(tab, "output 1.txt", sep="\t")
```

So I would like a function that imports files 1 to 5 and exports them to outputs 1 to 5 respectively.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please have a look to [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a loop. For example, if you have your files in an array called `files`

```
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  input.filename <- files[i]
  load(input.filename, .GlobalEnv)
  tab<-table(df$A, df$B)

  output.filename <- paste("output ", i, ".txt", sep="")
  write.table(tab, output.filename, sep="\t")
}
```

Comment: It could be better if you have the just 5 files of interest in the same folder you can use `list.files` and store it as a list and then make the list inside the loop. So you avoid typing the name of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. However, I still have a problem if I put in the loop the following : tab_new[i]<-tab, I get the error "object 'tab_new' not found". Why?